# Graylog Search with Regex

Tags: logging, graylog2, graylog

In my graylog Server, I want to create a search-value which finds the folowing query: `ctxt__Error:"User \"USERNAME\" not found."`.
But I want to find ANY Error for every USERNAME. My Searchstring dowsnt work when I do this: `ctxt__Error:"User \"*\" not found."`
Is there another way to do this?

Comment: I'd recommend asking questions about Graylog in the [Graylog Community Forums](https://community.graylog.org/). There's just a bigger specialized audience than in StackOverflow.

Answer (score 8):

Only a few message fields are analyzed by default in Graylog, i. e. `message`, `full_message`, and `source`.

You can create a custom Elasticsearch index template, if you want other fields to be analyzed: http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/configuration/elasticsearch.html#custom-index-mappings

Other than that, it should be possible to use regular expressions (not simple wildcards) in the query, but the regular expression has to match the *complete* field:
http://docs.graylog.org/en/2.4/pages/queries.html#search-query-language

Example:

```
ctxt_Error:/User ".*" not found./
```

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;

try following

```
field_name:/regular expression/
```

example,

```
ctxt__Error:\User .* not found.\
```

The original accepted answer is behind the paywall, which belongs to Graylog Enterprise customers.

Please kindly refer to the answers from the Graylog community post-https://community.graylog.org/t/searching-via-regular-expression-possible/6008

Comment: Who paywalls answers on Stackoverflow? What BS is this?